# Check database after inserting data and update listview

Tags: php, android, mysql, real-time

What I know is how to download and upload data from the database.

But how do I control, whether a data has been uploaded on the database? And if a data has been uploaded, I want to know how to get this data to put this to the listview without reloading the whole database again? 
In other words I want to have the new written text in the listview in real time, like a messenger.

Comment: Javascript probably. You would want to do an AJAX post to a PHP file that does the database work and in the AJAX success function, you would just append a new row to your listview

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking off of @CptMisery's answer here, I agree that ajax would be useful for this.

I use this quite often when I'm writing to a database - as a form of callback to ensure data was actually written.  First, here's the code you'd execute in JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'some_php_page.php',      
    data: { data:data },        
    success:function(data){                                                                                                                                                                        

      if ( data == 0 ) { 
        console.log("item has been updated");
      } else {
        console.log("item has NOT been updated");       
      }
    }                                                
  }); //close ajax
```

What this does is the ajax call sends the variable `data` as a POST to your `some_php_page.php`.  You can send multiple items like this: `data: { data:data, variable1:variable1, age:age, date:date }.`  The PHP page does something, (e.g. - writes to the database), and if it's successful, you have PHP `echo "0"`, otherwise you have it `echo "1"`.  The ajax success call happens once the `some_php_page.php` returns a value.  The success call reads that value and then does something.  This is a relatively simple way to accomplish (I think) what you're looking to do.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to have `some_php_page.php` return the ID of the new item. This would allow you to include it in the HTML for the new listview item which will make updates easier (if updating an item in the listview is possible)

Comment: Thank you for all solutions. Okay the solution is Ajax. I have not done anything with Ajax, but I try it. Practice creates masters.

Comment: Be sure to mark my answer as correct if it helped.  If you need more help with the implementation of ajax, there are literally TONS of posts on SO that should help guide you.